# Rails Include filtered model in Json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have the following controller code

```
respond_with(@employees) do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @employees.to_json(:include => :shifts) }
end
```

What do i have to do if i want to filter the shifts which are included? For example by a date. 
I have to be able to set the filter parameters in the controller.

Edit:
I thought about using :method but it creates another variable in the json object. It has to be called "shifts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
format.json { render :json => @employees.includes(:shifts).where("shifts.date > ?", your_date_here).to_json(:include => :shifts) }
```

Comment: Wow thanks almost perfect. But it should also include employees who don't have any shifts